# Silence ExpressionChanged in this particular use case? Not fixing the error but don't display it on the console, stackblitz inside

Tags: angular, angular-errorhandler

[Related to my question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62239283/angular-9-display-number-of-change-detection-cycles-on-the-ui-stackblitz-inside) and you can find the [stackblitz here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4sk7cn)

I understand why the error shows up and it is indeed correct the fact that it is showing up. Although this is a non-production use case where I want to see the number of change detection cycles in a dev component on the UI rather than in the console.

This of course triggers the error above `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` which is correct to show up due to how change detection works, the number on the UI will always be 1 cycle smaller than the real number which is in the console.

I don't want these numbers to be equal because it would be a recursive loop trying to force change detection on the UI every time that number changes.

However, the error message that results here is polluting the console in an annoying way and I would like to silence it.